# Excel macro Runtime Error : 1004

Tags: excel, filter, vba

I just started macros yesterday, every thing was going fine until I got this problem. Every time I try to run this code I get

> Run time 1004 error.

What the code does is assign a value to the acct_cre_mth_id filter.

I googled it and found one solution was to rename the filter, I have done that but it is of no use.

I have the given code but for different filter It works fine, but only for this particular
filter I am having a problem.

```
Sheets("Sheet6").Select
 ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("acct_cre_mth_id"). _
    ClearAllFilters
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("acct_cre_mth_id"). _
    CurrentPage = "1321"
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("acct_cre_mth_id"). _
    ClearAllFilters
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("acct_cre_mth_id"). _
    CurrentPage = "1322"
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("acct_cre_mth_id"). _
    ClearAllFilters
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("acct_cre_mth_id"). _
    CurrentPage = "1323"
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("acct_cre_mth_id"). _
    ClearAllFilters
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("acct_cre_mth_id"). _
    CurrentPage = "1324"
End Sub
```

Comment: Is your PivotTable really named "PivotTable1" in all sheets ? To find out click in the PivotTable and check in the text box left to the formula box where named ranges normally are displayed. This may cause the type of error you are getting. Also, your code is very weird in that it sets many times the same filter and clears it.  All the intermediary steps will not be shown to the user... only the "1324" filter will remain. Finally, you might want to learn about the `with` keyword which would reduce redundancy in your code.